# Regular Expresssion Quantifer - Can you use it to find non sequential matches?

Tags: regex

`enter code here`I am looking for a sting that occurs 5 times. (this is my string)  I want to use an alerting system to see if this string is present 5 times, but not sequentially. If it occurs 5 times all is happy  if it occurs less its not happy.

Test doc

```
this is my string a bunch of text this is my string even more text this is my string more text   blah blah blah this is my string and we are almost there this is my string

If I use (.this.is.my.string){5} it works on the following data
this is my string this is my string this is my string this is my string this is my string
```

However if I have a large space between each string (filled with other text) I cannot find it.  I have tried greedy and non greedy and it doesnt help.  This string when in production will be search HTML Source code.

This is a snip of the source code  The string I am searching for is div class='proxy'  I need to verify it is present 5 times.

```
<div class='proxy'><p class='proxyname'>DefaultRemoteProxy (version : 2.41.0)<p class='proxyid'>id : 192.168.0.180:5555, OS : VISTA</p><div     class='tabs'><ul><li class='tab' type='browsers'><a title='test slots' href='#'>Browsers</a></li><li class='tab' type='config'><a title='node     configuration' href='#'>Configuration</a></li></ul></div><div class='content'><div type='browsers' class='content_detail'><p class='protocol'     >WebDriver</p><p>v:34<img src='/grid/resources/org/openqa/grid/images/chrome.png' width='16' height='16' title='{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver,     platform=VISTA, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=1, version=34}' />
</p><p>v:5<img src='/grid/resources/org/openqa/grid/images/safari.png' width='16' height='16' title='{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, platform=VISTA, browserName=safari, maxInstances=1, version=5}' />
</p><p>v:10<img     src='/grid/resources/org/openqa/grid/images/internet_explorer.png' width='16' height='16' title='{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, platform=VISTA, browserName=iexplore, maxInstances=1, version=10}' />
</p><p>v:28<img src='/grid/resources/org/openqa/grid/images/firefox.png' width='16' height='16' title='{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, platform=VISTA, browserName=firefox, maxInstances=1, version=28}' />
</p></div><div type='config' class='content_detail'><p>nodeConfig:node-config-service.json</p><p>port:5555</p><p>servlets:[] /p><p>host:192.168.0.180</p><p>cleanUpCycle:5000</p><p>browserTimeout:0</p><p>hubHost:seleniumgrid2.domain.com</p><p>registerCycle:5000</p><p>capabilityM    atcher:org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher</p><p>newSessionWaitTimeout:-    1</p><p>url:192.168.0.180:5555</p><p>remoteHost:192.168.0.180:5555</p><p>prioritizer:null</p><p>register:true</p><p>throwOnCapabilityNotPresent:true</p><p    >nodePolling:5000</p><p>proxy:org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy</p><p>maxSession:5</p><p>role:node</p><p>jettyMaxThreads:-    1</p><p>hubPort:4444</p><p>timeout:300000</p></div></div></div></div><div id='rightColumn'>
```

Comment: Do you need at least 5 times, or 5 times exactly?

Comment: would rather match exactly 5, but it will never be more than 5 so at least would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lookahead you can do:

```
^(?=(?:[\s\S]*div class='proxy'){5})[\s\S]+$
```

Comment: That matched "this is my string this is my string this is my string this is my string this is my string"

Comment: Yes it will match any input that has 5 or more of `this is my string` ( I will provide an option to match exact 5 matches also )

Comment: @sjustice Is 5 or matches good enough for you or you want exact 5?

Comment: From my understanding he diddnt want sequential matches?

Comment: at least 5 will work.  I need it to get "unhappy" when there are less than 5.  Also there will never be more than 5.   We are monitoring 5 servers.  When the server is talking to our "grid" an entry is created for that machine.  There will never be more than 5 machines and we want to set off an alarm if one or more of these machines disappear.  That make things even more "muddy"?   @martin  yes that is correct I can get sequental to work.  I need to serch for a string that occurs 5 times in random source code. I can find sequential already.

Comment: @Martyn: This regex is not finding sequential matches. Searched string can be anywhere.

Comment: @sjustice: Above regex would work for you in that case just make sure to use DOTALL (s) flag in whatever language/script you are using for this.

Comment: ok.  It might be because its searching source code. but it didnt work.  Let me scrub out ip's etc and I will paste the source code.

Comment: What tool/language are you using for your regex?

Comment: @anubhava  I have edited my orginal post with a snippet of source code.

Comment: What tool/language are you using for your regex?

Comment: @anubhava  The user guide is not clear, but here is a link http://sitescope.tellurian.net/SiteScope/docs/regexp.htm  I am using the build in editor  as well as "the Regulator" for testing.

Comment: But your input has only one `div class='proxy'` that's why it is not matching.

Comment: I could not fit the whole code in the post.  I assure you I am testing against the whole code with 5 instances of that division.

Comment: @anubhava That did that job. Thank you very much.  For anyone looking here is the final expression. ^(?=(?:[\s\S]*div class='proxy'){5})[\s\S]+$

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
 .*(this is my string.*){5}
```

although this might also match if the text occurs more than 5 times...

Answer (score 0):

Could probably be done better than this:

```
((this\sis\smy\sstring\s)[^\1].*){4}this\sis\smy\sstring
```

Comment: I tested with the app "the regulater" and it did not work.  I can get it to work up to ((this\sis\smy\sstring\s)[^\1].*).  It will return the value 5 seperate times, but when add the next step it returns no results.  Also I had to replace the \s with . to get it to work.  I guess this editor is just pickie.